# vscode interactive notebooks nuget directory error

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#-interactive, dotnet-interactive, .net-interactive

I was trying to include a nuget package in my C# cell, like the example below:

```
#r "nuget: PackageIWantToInclude"
```

when suddenly, I got a similar error like this:

```
Error: PackageManagement Error 3217 The source directory 'D:\MyLocalDirectory' not found
```

note that I have not made any edits on the settings pointing to any directory with the address `'D:\MyLocalDirectory'`. I've also looked for a solution elsewhere without any success. Can anyone give me a hint on how to bring the source directory back into its default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, `vscode interactive notebook` uses the nuget configuration included in `Nuget.Config` found in "C:\Users{computer name}\AppData\Roaming\NuGet".

In that current machine where the error occurs, I have some local package sources included that were already non-existent, though they were already disabled, as indicated when viewed using this command `dotnet nuget list source`.

What I did was to remove the non-existent package source from the `Nuget.Config` file--in this example that would be:

```
    <add key="NonExistentSource" value="D:\MyLocalDirectory" />
```

and then I restarted the notebook kernel by:

- opening Command Palette (CTRL+SHFT+P) or under View>>Command Palette..
- and then selecting the restart notebook's kernel[image: Restart]